# MySQLdb: how to connect with phpMyAdmin

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-connection, mysql-python

I have a LAMP server and then I installed MySQLdb for my Python scripts. Now I can't access the MySQL (from LAMP) from Python scripts because it isn't connecting to the MySQLdb, and also I can't access the MySQLdb with phpMyAdmin with (root root). I got "#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server" error. Is it possible to connect to one db with Python and phpMyAdmin?

Here is my Python code, which can't connect to the LAMP MySQL, but can connect to the MySQLdb:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3303, user="root", passwd="rootroot", db="test")
cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "CREATE TABLE TT(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)"


cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Post your code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting `#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server` when logging in to `phpmyadmin`, then edit `phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file and change:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';

to:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

You might want to visit this link:
http://blog.ryantremaine.com/2011/03/2002-cannot-log-in-to-mysql-server.html

**UPDATE:**

you wud not have configured your php.ini well and so that it cannot connect to mysql server.

1. Wrong path for the mysql.sock
   mysql.sock is the instance of the mysql, so first you have to find where does it place at.
   You may find it at "/tmp/mysql.sock" or "/var/mysql/mysql.sock".

Go to your php.ini and make sure the value for "pdo_mysql.default_socket", "mysql.default_socket", "mysqli.default_socket" is the right path.

Then restart your web server and try again.

**ELSE** 
Try this:

Go to config.inc.php and check for the following line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'YOUR USER NAME IS HERE';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'AND YOU PASSWORD IS HERE';
```

Check whether the user name and password that you gave is present or not

Comment: I did it, but that's not helped

Comment: Check for the user name and password in the config.inc.php file.

Comment: I guess u shud check the config.inc.php file.Check my updated answer

Comment: I checked config.inc.php and add password there, my script still connected to the mysqldb, not to the lapm_mysql

Comment: mysql.sock path is set to the lamp_mysql, in case of this I can't connect to the mysqldb with phpmyadmin, but I cant find any other mysql.sock on my fs

Comment: You need to install the server package:

sudo yum install mysql-server
After installation, you have to start the service:

sudo service mysqld start

Comment: I found mysql.sock path and chage it, but result is the same. I can connect to the mysqldb form terminal and python script, but can't with phpmyadmin

Comment: thank you, I just installed MySQL WorkBench and it works fine, no more phpmyadmin...